# App crashes with background attribute

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, background, fragment

I am trying to set the background of my fragments and the strangest thing is occurring. Whenever I type `android:background="@drawable/background"` my app crashses. No matter what file it is on, something always makes it crash.

The background shows perfectly in the preview of the fragment, but it doesn't work when I run the app. I tried using src instead of background and that didn't work either.

Yes, I did try and change the background through Java instead of xml and I got the same error:

```
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at com.sap.app.LogoFragment.onCreateView(LogoFragment.java:16)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16829)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16829)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16829)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16829)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16829)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16829)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2581)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16829)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2186)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1349)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1532)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6328)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5450)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
01-19 21:21:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(7072):     at co
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment android:name="com.sap.app.SelectionFragment"
          android:id="@+id/selectionFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment android:name="com.sap.app.SplashFragment"
          android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment android:name="com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment"
          android:id="@+id/userSettingsFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

splash.xml (loaded if user is not logged in):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!--
        <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp" />
    -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp" 
        android:background="#FF8000">.

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/header_lettering"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <!-- <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip -->
        <!-- android:layout_width="match_parent" -->
        <!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:layout_gravity="top" -->
        <!-- android:paddingBottom="10dp" -->
        <!-- android:paddingTop="10dp" -->
        <!-- android:textColor="#000000" /> -->

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_logo.xml loaded by the splash.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sap_logo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/acronym"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sap_acronym" />

</LinearLayout>
```

LogoFragment.java:

```
package com.sap.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class LogoFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stu

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_logo, container, false);
        return view;
    }



}
```

Comment: Try posting your XML layout. From the exception description, it seems like you are trying to inflate a layout that does not exist or cannot be found. Also, if you are inflating a custom view, you may need to put in the full class path (including package name) when inflating the XML layout.

Comment: I can add all of the XML layouts but there are a lot of them because I am using nested fragments.

Comment: All of the code is in the example

Comment: As logcat says, the issue is with layout file of `LogoFragment`, so please post only that xml layout file which is being used in `LogoFragment`.

Comment: Do u have image with  the name background in the drawable folder??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me.

First create **activity_main.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:id="@+id/main_layout" >

  <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="200dp" 
    android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_logo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:src="@drawable/sap_logo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/acronym"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:src="@drawable/sap_acronym" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Second Thing create **MainActivity.java**:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    My_Fragment  frag=new My_Fragment();
    FragmentManager FM = getSupportFragmentManager();       
    FragmentTransaction transaction=FM.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,frag,"fragment1");
    transaction.commit();


 }
}
```

Third Create your Fragement class:

**My_Fragment.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class My_Fragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_logo, container, false);
    return view;
 }  
}
```

Hope it should work and please let me know. Thanks